# Soft rear suspension on Landrover Defender too low

Tags: technic, vehicle

Can't answer this officially because I haven't enough points but the photos on the only other answer are of the front end, the problem I had on the rear was that the bottom shock absorber brown crossbar should be in the cross hole on the wishbone ie the hole nearest the wheel not the round hole

Comment: 10 points for you. Can you try to upload photo now? Press edit at bottom of post content to edit and add photos.

Comment: Hi Trev and welcome to Bricks - I assume you mean the question about [Issues with my LEGO Land Rover Defender - Low rear](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/12904/56)? Unfortunately I can't convert a question into an answer on the other post, but you should be able to answer that question now - if you're able to do so today we can then remove this question.

Comment: "_Can't answer this officially because I haven't enough points_" That's strange, answering should be open to anyone, regardless of reputation levels. Perhaps you have tried to add a [comment, which indeed requires 50 reputation](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). But adding an answer and asking a question are [linked together](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts) as privileges and are [available from 1 rep](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). So if you could ask this, you should be able to answer too, can you please check it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question but an answer to an existing question. It looks like you have enough reputation now to answer the question.